# In endochondral bone formation, why does only hyaline cartilage get ossified to form bone?

Tags: human-anatomy, bone, cartilage

There are three types of cartilage: hyaline, fibrous and elastic cartilage.
Fibrous cartilage does not have perichondrium...so it does not take part in ossification because perichondrium needs to develop into periosteum.
Hyaline cartilage has more matrix in comparison to elastic cartilage. Hence, during ossification the quicker spreading of calcification of the matrix will lead to the death of the chondrocytes which will develop into osteoprogenitor cells. Is my theory correct?

Comment: '... calcification of the matrix will lead to the death of the chondrocytes which will develop into osteoprogenitor cells.' How can dead cells develop into living ones?

Answer (score -2):

yes this is correct, i think hyline cartilage gets transformed to bone more quickly due to the fact that is has the matrix which is closest to bone in terms of density, also the cells are located more closely, therefore it is easier to convert this tissue to bone.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! This sounds reasonable, but without supporting references only an expert in this area can evaluate your answer. Consequently, answers are much more likely to receive a favorable response if they include supporting references (primary literature is best). ——— You may also wish to take the [tour] and then consult the help pages on the standards for additional advice on [Answer] effectively. Thanks! 